# npm publish not working, no progress after showing total file count

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I have a public package, which I have been updating for quite some time.
All of a sudden, when I am trying to do `npm publish` it is no longer working.
Its stuck at here:
[image]
Tried oher solution from stack overflow:

```
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm proxy
# restrat system after wards
```

None of them seems to work. What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I added new features to my package. For testing purpose I added some video files to my package for testing. So overall package size became too big.
I added a `.npmignore` file and added my test directory to be ignored from npm  publish.
And now its working!